# Access correct Tab using URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I'm using Joshua Gatcke's 99Lime HTML Kickstart framework for prototyping.
It uses an implementation of the jQuery tabs and I was wondering if it's possible to access a tab directly by the URL.

So for example, I have a page, with in this case, static content.
One is `#settings` and another is `#users`.
I want to redirect a user to `/dashboard#users` and have the users tab display immediately.

Is this something that's possible?

Comment: Yes, there are loads of examples of this here on SO. Basically you check the `document.location.hash` value when the page is loaded, and open the appropriate tab with javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voilá:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
        $('ul.tabs a[href^="' + document.location.hash + '"]').click();
    });

    if (document.location.hash.length) {
        $(window).trigger('hashchange');            
    }
})​;​
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PpwfH/)

*Edit:*

Upon reading your question thoroughly, I realized that this is all you need:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (document.location.hash.length) {
        $('ul.tabs a[href^="' + document.location.hash + '"]').click();
    }
})​;​
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it is. Have you tried anything? Or are you just asking if there is some out-of-the-box way to do this?

In case it is the first, here is some pseudo code to do this (I guess clicking on a tab displays it, right?):

```
window.onhashchange = function(e) {
    By.id(e.newUrl).click()
}
```

PS: using the [By micro-library](https://gist.github.com/1455456).

Comment: Thanks, I tried linking to the url with the hash but couldn't figure out exactly how to use that hash in a javascript. I think I found a similar solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687960/jquery-tabs-where-the-tab-content-can-be-linked-to